# Parameter estimations through non linear regression in R with multiple dependent and independent variables

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression

I have the following exponential decay model:

[image]

I want to estimate the following paramaters through a non linear regression:

λ0, λ1, λ2

My simplfied version of my data set looks like this:

```
X(i=1,t=7)   X(i=2,t=7)       

0.5             0.3
0.6             0.3
0.55            0.4
0.66            0.35
0.5             0.35

t      R(i=1)    R(i=2)

1      0.1       0.1
2      0.125     0.125
3      0.15      0.17
4      0.2       0.2
5      0.25      0.21
6      0.4       0.27
7      0.45      0.35

n=6
```

The problem I face is the nested sum operator within another sum operator, as well as the fact that my dependet variable `Xi,t` as well as my independet variable `Ri,t-s` are spread over two columns. Up unitil now the regression I have done were simple linear regression with one column for `X` and one column for `R`so I am kinda lost now.